# Break the maximum capacity of the List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have added 10 HStacks inside a List. When I added the 11th HStack, the Xcode showed an error.

[This page](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/swiftui-tips-and-tricks) taught me to use Group to break the 10 children limit. But that didn't work for me. How can I add the 11th HStack in a List?

---

Works:

```
        List {

            Text("內部培訓問卷調查")

            HStack {
                Text("姓")
                TextField("陳", text: self.$name)
            }

            ...

            HStack {
                Text("電話號碼")
                TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
            }

    }
```

---

Not working:

```
        List {

            Text("內部培訓問卷調查")

            HStack {
                Text("姓")
                TextField("陳", text: self.$name)
            }

            ...

            HStack {
                Text("電話號碼")
                TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
            }

            HStack { //The extra HStack
                Text("電話號碼2")
                TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
            }

    }
```

With these error messages:

```
    <unknown>:0: error: ambiguous reference to member 'buildBlock()'
SwiftUI.ViewBuilder:3:24: note: found this candidate
    public static func buildBlock() -> EmptyView
                       ^
SwiftUI.ViewBuilder:4:24: note: found this candidate
    public static func buildBlock<Content>(_ content: Content) -> Content where Content : View
                       ^
SwiftUI.ViewBuilder:3:24: note: found this candidate
    public static func buildBlock<C0, C1>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1) -> TupleView<(C0, C1)> where C0 : View, C1 : View
                       ^
```

---

If using group, the app can be compiled but text are overlapped (list is not looks as expected; check the image below):

```
        List {

        Group {

            Text("內部培訓問卷調查")

            HStack {
                Text("姓")
                TextField("陳", text: self.$name)
            }

            ...

            HStack {
                Text("電話號碼")
                TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
            }

        }

        Group {
            HStack {
                Text("電話號碼2")
                TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
            }
        }

    }
```

[image: overlapping text]

Comment: can you post your code or any error messages that you are getting? Usually as mentioned in the same article we can go beyond 10 views using `Group`s

Comment: I updated the question. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Make `Group` & add last 6 `HStack` inside it.
don't use `Group` with both `Text` & `HStack`.

Comment: You are repeating a pattern (HStack + Text + TextField). That makes it ideal to use an array and then a ForEach view that can hold as many views as you like without having to worry about Groups.

Comment: @KetanOdedra I tried Text in a Group and other HStacks in a Group. The UI looks as expected! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, Your Solution :

Make `Group` of `HStack`.

```
   List {

            Text("內部培訓問卷調查")

            HStack { //1
                Text("姓")
                TextField("陳", text: self.$name)
            }

            HStack { //2
                Text("電話號碼")
                TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
            }

            HStack { //3
                Text("電話號碼2")
                TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
            }

            HStack { //4
                Text("電話號碼3")
                TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
            }

            HStack { //5
                Text("電話號碼4")
                TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
            }

            //Make Group Here
            Group {

                HStack { //6
                    Text("電話號碼5")
                    TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
                }

                HStack { //7
                    Text("電話號碼6")
                    TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
                }

                HStack { //8
                    Text("電話號碼7")
                    TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
                }

                HStack { //9
                    Text("電話號碼8")
                    TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
                }

                HStack { //10
                    Text("電話號碼9")
                    TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
                }

                HStack { //11
                    Text("電話號碼10")
                    TextField("首先選擇國家/地區", text: self.$name)
                }
            }

        }.padding()
```

But as @kontiki said that,

You are repeating a pattern.
so, make an array of it. and use `ForEach`.